# (Drawing on iPad) Do they sell artist gloves that cover all 5 fingers?

Tags: tool-selection, tool-identification

I use Procreate on the iPad, I want to avoid getting smudges on the screen, but still want to use my fingers to zoom and pan, etc. I have tried using a Matte screen protector and it helps reduce smudges but the image quality up gets worse.

So I think the perfect solution is to use a glove that covers all 5 fingers. Of course, it has to be made from a material that allow touch detection to work.

But I don't know if a tool like this exists. Can anybody enlighten me?

---

- Edit: The smudges I care about are the ones caused by the fingertips (of my index and thumb) interacting with the screen. I own 2-fingered drawing gloves and I'm using them. But since the bare skin of my thumb and index finger touches the screen, it causes smudges. Here I'm asking for a similar glove that covers all 5 of my fingers.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147006/discussion-on-question-by-khoa-vo-drawing-on-ipad-do-they-sell-artist-gloves-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

They were not called "artist's gloves" but I did pick up a cheap pair of five fingered gloves that supported touch screen capacitance at a local hardware store, so yes.

Comment: But can you use it to draw? Does it allow your hand to glide on the screen?

Comment: Yes. And a quick google search turns up dozens of five fingered touch screen compatible gloves. I would imagine they all glide on the screen since they would be pretty useless if they didn't. Are you stuck on the need for them to be called "art gloves" or is there some other reason these many choices do not work for you?

Comment: Also may I add: can you list a link to a product that you think would work? Just to get something concrete out here.